How to get a deep clone of an entity object
Is there a way of getting a second object for an entity that is a different PHP object (with different PHP objects inside as well)?
I tried using https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy with a node entity object, and it crashed having exhausted 1GB of memory.

clone $entity clones the entity object with cloned fields and field items. Isn't that a second object with different objects inside?

Thanks! I had no idea entity objects supported that. Feel free to put that as an answer to get credit :)

You can use the PHP standard clone operator:
$clone = clone $entity;

The base class for content entities implements the magic method ContentEntityBase::__clone() to deep clone the entity including the field objects.
